# offer him of offer to him? lent him or lent to him?

Tags: indirect-objects

Which one is correct? (or if both are correct, which one is better)

1. > I offered him a job.

or

2. > I offered a job to him.

---

1. > I lent him a pen.

or

2. > I lent a pen to him.

Comment: I feel that you're asking the wrong questions here titan. Why should one of them be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both of these examples, **him** can be use either as an indirect object, which is placed between the verb and the object:

> 1) I offered **him** a job.

or as part of a to-prepositional phrase, which is placed after the object.

> 2) I offered a job **to him**.

Both are correct and the meaning is the same, but (1) is usually a lot more common- see this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lent%20him%20money%2C%20lent%20money%20to%20him&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clent%20him%20money%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clent%20money%20to%20him%3B%2Cc0). For more information about indirect objects, see [here](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/double-object-verbs).

Comment: Hi. sorry for the lent a job. it was pen but I confused it with the upper sentence. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is known as dative shift. Not all verbs can be alternated like this, but for those that can, the meanings are equivalent. You may depending on context hear one version more often than the other.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was looking for the rule behind it/ a name to call it by.

Comment: You're welcome. "Dative" is a term borrowed from languages like Latin and Greek, which is why its not otherwise common

Comment: I learned all those grammatical terms when I learned Latin, but I do use them (it's part of the curriculum) quite a bit when I teach German